# show index of array in solidiy

Tags: arrays, backend, blockchain, solidity

here is the problem. we have an array that contains three different strings. I want to create a function that when I call the function, it will show me the first string; second call would be second string and third call will show the third string in array.
so how should I write this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically use a counter and a return function but since you will be changing a state variable it won't be gas optimized and very unuseful you can check the contract below.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract ArrayItemReturn {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter public indexCounter;

    string[] strings = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"];

    function returnItem() external returns(string memory) {
        require(indexCounter.current() < strings.length, "You reached the end of the array");
        indexCounter.increment();

        return strings[indexCounter.current()-1];
    }
}
```

Another approach could be getting the data from your Dapp since you can just query the index you want.